# Postgres Time/Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model

I have created a method that lists future dates, the method uses psql's NOW() type. I have been instructed not to use this because the time in the database is different from the time in the system.

Example: where(concert_start_time > NOW)

This is in my rails model. Is there an alternative to using NOW().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Time` object

```
where('concert_start_time > ?', Time.now)
```

Comment: I didn't think that would work, but it did. Tests are green. Thanks!

Comment: easiest way to check is to print the query and add `to_sql` at the end, it will show you the generated query.